# mysql add foreign key error 1215

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, constraints

I'm trying to insert foreign keys into my database, but somehowe i can't get this one working while my other foreign keys are fine. I searched for answers already, and i checked my types, but still can't find the problem. (using mysql workbench)

```
Table 1: klant
klantnaam VARCHAR(45) PK NN
fabriek VARCHAR(45) PK NN
machine VARCHAR(45) NN

Table 2: machine
machine VARCHAR(45) PK NN
fabriek VARCHAR(45) NN
```

now i want machine.fabriek to be a foreign key (to klant.fabriek).

So under tab "Foreign Keys" i add a foreign key like:

```
name: fk_fabriek
Reference Table: 'slalist' . 'klant'
Column: fabriek
Reference Column: fabriek
```

when i try to apply this changes, i get this error

```
1215: Cannot add foreign key constraint 
SQL Statement: 
CREATE TABLE `slalist`.`machine` ( 
  `machine` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL, 
  `fabriek` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (`machine`), 
  INDEX `fk_fabriek_idx` (`fabriek` ASC), 
  CONSTRAINT `fk_fabriek` 
    FOREIGN KEY (`fabriek`) 
    REFERENCES `slalist`.`klant` (`fabriek`) 
    ON DELETE NO ACTION 
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

Is there anyone who knows what i'm doing wrong? Searched half the web, but couldn't find a fitting answer.

Thanks in advance!

Geert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A FOREIGN KEY in one table points to a PRIMARY KEY in another table. and in your case 'fabriek' is not primary key.

Comment: Thanks for your respond. I made a type mistake, 'fabriek' is a primary key tough. Meanwhile i made a EER in mySQL Workbench and tryed to convert it to SQL script, but unfortunately i got the same error. I made a screenshot from my EER, maybe u can see what i'm doing wrong. http://tinypic.com/r/20z7hjp/5 is the link

Comment: posted EER image is too small. one suggestion check your tables has innodb engine

Comment: http://i39.tinypic.com/jgntkg.jpg check that one, click on image, that will be big enough. I checked that too, every table is using InnoDB

Comment: can you see a mistake?